# How do I change a database entry when I enter text into an input?

Tags: php

The logic is this: the text is displayed from the database, next to it there is a box to enter, after you enter text and click on the link 'edit' record in the database should change. I did it only if the text is static. Everything works. But I need to take text from input. How do I do that? Can you please help me?

I added the 'hidden input' because I've seen similar solutions with it, but I can't get the values.

```
<form class="msg-wall" method="post" action="/vendor/wall.php">
        <?php foreach($check_message as $row) { ?>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="msg"><?= $row['message'] ?></p>
                <input type="text" name="edit">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                <a href="?ed=<?= $row['id'] ?>">edit</a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

</form>
```

**wall.php:**

```
if (isset($_GET['ed'])) {
    $id = $_GET['ed'];
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE message SET message = 'ffffdf' WHERE id = $id");
    header('Location: ../profile.php');
}
```

Comment: Your form is set to us `POST` yet your vulnerable PHP/SQL is using `GET`

Comment: But I did the same delete button using GET requests and everything worked in this form. I want to use both POST and GET here. Can't I do it this way?

Comment: Better be consistent. Set both as POST is better. On the other hand please try using prepared statement in DB update. It appears that you are using loop to get data from multiple records. Please use AJAX in your case

Comment: You are generating HTML in a loop - will there be more than 1 `div.content` generated? If yes you have other problems

Comment: Use `GET` to retrieve data and `POST` to update records - that is generally the considered practise

Comment: Yes, it will be more than 1.

Comment: Can you please show me approximately what a GET request should look like here?

Comment: I misread the html - thought there were duplicate IDs - ignore that previous comment about more issues.

Comment: But there will still be problems due to duplicate names. Names must be unique, as well as ids. You'd be better off creating an entire form for each of your elements. Use `post` and replace that link with a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GET` to update records in a db is not a good idea. A GET request can easily be modified to affect other records, it can be bookmarked, shared and more. The generally accepted method for updating records is to use `POST` - which can, in theory, be used in conjunction with GET if it is really important to pass variables that way(such as modifying the form action)

The original code is vulnerable to SQL injection so when that vulnerability exists in conjunction with GET requests you are not far from problems. The following tries to mitigate risks by using POST in combination with "[Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)" - the comments made through the code should offer further insight

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    #db connect
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'xxx'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    
    try{
        mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
        $connect=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        echo 'boom!';
    }
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['ed'], $_POST['edit'] ) ){
        # generate basic update statement with suitable placeholders
        $sql='update `message` set `message` = ? where id = ?';
        
        # create the "Prepared Statement" object
        $stmt=$connect->prepare( $sql );
        
        # bind the placeholders to variables ( these do not need to be defined at this stage with mysqli )
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $edit, $ed );
        
        # assign variables
        $edit=$_POST['edit'];
        $ed=$_POST['ed'];
        
        # commit the statement
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        
        # go to the winchester and have a nice cold pint
        exit( header( 'Location: ../profile.php' ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Message Wall</title>
        <style>
            form textarea{
                border:none;
                background:whitesmoke;
                width:80%;
                height:5rem;
            }
            .content{
                width:50%;
                border-bottom:1px dotted grey;
                margin:0 0 2rem 0;
                padding:0 0 2rem 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <!--
            not disclosed - the process by which the recordset / array is generated... so assumed below
            
            A single form with multiple input elements of the same name needs "Javascript"
            to aid the distinction of which records to update. The recordset is assumed to be a 
            multidimensional array created by iterating through a db query recordset.
            
            Using hidden inputs for both the message to write to db and the ID we can target
            these using "Javascript" prior to submitting the form.
        -->
        <?php
        
            # assumed method for generating recordset
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' ){
                $sql='select * from message';
                $res=$connect->query($sql);
                $check_message=array();
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_assoc() )$check_message[]=$rs;
            }
        
        ?>
        <form class='msg-wall' method='post' action='/vendor/wall.php'>
            <?php 
                foreach( $check_message as $row ) { 
            ?>
                <div class='content'>
                    <!-- original message -->
                    <p class='msg'><?= $row['message'] ?></p>
                    
                    <!-- a Copy of original message - field will be cleared when clicked -->
                    <textarea name='edit'><?= $row['message'] ?></textarea>
                    
                    <!-- rather than a hyperlink, a button makes sense -->
                    <button type='button' data-id='<?= $row['id'];?>'>Edit</button>
                </div>
            <?php 
                } 
            ?>
            <!-- these will be updated by js prior to submission -->
            <input type='hidden' name='edit' />
            <input type='hidden' name='ed' />
        </form>
        <script>
            const form=document.querySelector('form.msg-wall');
            // for each "button" - add an event listener to watch for "click" events
            form.querySelectorAll('div.content button').forEach( bttn => {
                bttn.onclick=function(e){
                    // update the two hidden elements
                    form.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="edit"]').value=this.parentNode.querySelector('textarea').value;
                    form.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="ed"]').value=this.dataset.id;
                    
                    // for convenience in testing THIS script, the "action" attribute needs to be the SAME page... this does NOT need to be used in final version
                    form.action=location.href;
                    
                    // submit the form
                    form.submit();
                };
            });
            
            // clear the textarea if clicked but restore the value if unchanged
            form.querySelectorAll('textarea[name="edit"]').forEach( n=>{
                n.onclick=function(e){ if( this.value==this.defaultValue )this.value=''; };
                n.onblur=function(e){ if( this.value=='' )this.value=this.defaultValue; };
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

I modified your code I hope this produces what you want:

**UDPATE**: I reduce the form area and create multiple forms to each rows and added row ID to all form elements and that is worked for me

```
    <?php foreach($check_message as $row): ?>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="msg-wall" method="post" action="#" id="form_<?= $row['id'] ?>">    
            <p class="msg"><?= $row['message'] ?></p>
            <input type="text" name="new_message_<?= $row['id'] ?>" form="form_<?= $row['id'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>" form="form_<?= $row['id'] ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" form="form_<?= $row['id'] ?>"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>`
```

**wall.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST["new_message_" . $_POST['id']])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $new_message = $_POST['new_message_' . $_POST['id']];

    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE message SET message = $new_message WHERE id = $id");
    header('Location: ../profile.php');
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed when I entered text into the input and clicked the button(

Comment: There is no need to append the id to other input names if you're creating a new form with each iteration. That will only complicate handling the submission. Also, this still remains open to SQL injection.

Comment: @El_Vanja I think that will simplify handling the submission, because this php handle all multiple user request (which can happen at the same time). If I only send ID with the hidden elements, the last value of new_message is overwrite other users new_message fields

Comment: No. Each request a user makes is handled individually. My submission of the same form has nothing to do with your submission of the same form. And there is no way a single user can submit multiple edits when you have separate forms.